# Packagecontrol.io down

Tags: package, sublimetext3

Hi I am trying to download a package on sublime but for hte past two days packagecontrol.io doesnt seem to be working. Keep getting a 502 bad gateway error. 
Is there any one else facing the same issue?

Comment: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/package-control-outage/41274

Answer (score 1):

Basically the plugin maintainer is recovering the database server from a file system corruption. Here's more information about it: [sublime text forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/package-control-outage/41274).

A user there recommended the google-cached version of the website if you need it.