# Sublime Text no packages available - Package Control issue 502

Tags: sublimetext3

Having issues installing new packages in Sublime Text. It says that there are no packages available.

It suggests to see packagecontrol.io/docs/troubleshooting for help.

When you navigate to packagecontrol.io it shows a "502 Bad Gateway" error. Nothing useful to show in the console or debugger.

What is the issue and how to fix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Packagecontrol.io down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162970/packagecontrol-io-down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pacakagecontrol.io is currently down. It appears the server suffered some corruption issues. The admin of the server says they are working on upgrading to a new server, and hope to be back up soon.

From the Sublime HQ forum [Packagecontrol.io Admin]:

"The file system on the Package Control server suffered some corruption and a number of services required for the website are in a degraded state.

I am working on a new server and recovering as much data as possible from the PostgreSQL database. Unfortunately earlier this year the raw database size grew to the point where the current backup routine was no longer capable of running. I also had another child and I didn't have enough free time to work on a new backup solution - thus we will see how much can be salvaged. So far it seems like the vast majority of data should be intact, but there is no way to recover on the current machine due to insufficient disk space.

Unfortunately the original server was set up back in early 2012, and while I have a record of how to set it up, I need to move to a more modern approach (ansible) and OS release. This will also make it easier to recover in the case of future issues."

Direct link to the forum where updates are being given: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/package-control-outage/41274

**New update:** Possible work around until the new server is up [posted by a forum member]

"Quick tip for anyone who needs to install something now - Google has packagecontrol.io cached, so at least for the plugin I needed, I just clicked the little disclosure triangle in the google results, selected "cached" and got this:

https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:FgGP3l_yPTgJ:https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Elixir+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=safari
"

Link to forum post: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/package-control-outage/41274/31?u=destinyjv

Answer (score 0):

properly set the proxy info. You should add the proxy info via the menu Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings – User.

It should look like:

```
{
    "http_proxy": "yourproxy.com:ip",
    "https_proxy": "yourproxy.com:ip"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting However, I found the issue and current solution from the Sublime HQ forums, direct from the admin of packagecontrol.io.
Apparently, the server was corrupted, being from 2012, and all the new info was too much for the standard backup procedures.

He said they hope to be back up yesterday Jan. 11th. So.. All we can do is wait for now. At least we don't have to waste time trying to troubleshoot an issue we can't fix.